# jQuery toggle arrow down 'ontoggle'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

Hi I have the following: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cXEZx/7/)

It's essentially an accordion toggle menu. What I am trying to do is rotate the arrow from the right position to a downward position once the menu has been toggled open. Upon the menu closing I would like the arrow to rotate back its rightward position. I have tried doing it by finding the CSS and

```
transform: rotate(-90deg)
```

However, the position of the arrow does not change. Thoughts? This is the `<script>`

```
//Dekstop Content
$('.content').each(function () {
    var $accordian = $(this);
    $accordian.find('.view').on('click', function () {
        $accordian.find('.content-body').slideUp();
        $accordian.find('span').css("transform", 'rotate(0deg);');
        if (!$(this).next().is(':visible')) {
            $(this).next().slideDown();
            $(this).find('span').css({"transform": 'rotate(90deg);'})
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You have both rotate(-90deg), one should be rotate(0deg) in your condition...

Comment: Why do have `$('#content').each(...)`? An id-selector will only find one (or no) elements.

Comment: Also, I think if you remove the `;` so it becomes: `.css('transform', 'rotate(-90deg)')` will fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.css` should look like this: `.css('Property-Name','Value')`

Try this code:

```
//Dekstop Content
$('#content').each(function () {
    var $accordian = $(this);
    $accordian.find('.view').on('click', function () {
        $accordian.find('.content-body').slideUp();
        $accordian.find('span').css('transform','rotate(0deg)'); // Changed
        if (!$(this).next().is(':visible')) {
            $(this).next().slideDown();
            $(this).find('span').css('transform', 'rotate(90deg)'); // Changed
        }
    });
});
```

Greetings from Vienna

Comment: I'd suggest also throwing a `span.updown { transition: all 0.4s linear; }` into the CSS for prettiness ([JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/cXEZx/10/)), but, regardless, +1.